# stationary points of multivariable equation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Given the equation z(x,y) = ycoshx+2(y-1)^2 and asked to locate the stationary points. So far I have:
Zx=ysinhx
Zy=coshx+4y-4
I have equated these both to zero and know that I need to find values for the x and y but am struggling. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: If $y=0$ then $coshx=4$, do you know how to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to find the stationary points of

$$z(x,y) = y \cosh x+2(y-1)^2$$

The partials are

$$z_x = y \sinh x, z_y = \cosh x+4 (y-1)$$

From $z_x$, we have

$$y \sinh x = 0 \implies x = 0 ~ \mbox{or}~ y = 0$$

We now have to use those two values separately in $z_y$.

Using $z_y$, when $x = 0$, we have

$$- 4 + 4 y + \cosh x = 0 \implies y = \dfrac{3}{4}$$

Using $z_y$, when $y = 0$, we have

$$-4 + \cosh x = 0 \implies x = \pm \cosh^{-1} (-4)$$

Summarizing, our three points are

$$(x, y) = \left(0, \dfrac{3}{4}\right), (-\cosh^{-1} (-4), 0), (\cosh^{-1} (-4), 0)$$

We can verify these using a contour plot

[image]